# Where "ac_status" variable is defined and how it works with autoconf / configure script?

Tags: autoconf

I'm looking to debug configure script created by autoconf to exactly know where it fails to find specific dependency. I see variable `ac_status` which comes to check after eval command in configure script which redirects output always to &5.

Where could I find information about `ac_status` - what it means, where can be it defined and by whom and how it works? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just variable to check ret val. Please, skip this question.